# How to add red asterisk(*) in label of text field In Flutter

Tags: flutter

How to add a red asterisk in the label of the text field  In Flutter.
[Please see here to find what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inm31.jpg). I tried, but I am getting error.

```
Container(
              width: 310,
              child: CTextField(
                decoration: new CInputDecoration(
                  isMandate: true,
                  labelText: 'First Name',
                  labelStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
                      color: Color(0xffb0b0b0),
                      fontSize: 19,
                      letterSpacing: 0.5),
                  
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
SizedBox(
  width: 310,
  child: TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
    label: RichText(
       text: TextSpan(
            text: 'Full Name',
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey),
              children: [
                 TextSpan(
                    text: ' *',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.red,
                    )
                 )
              ]
            ),
          ),
          floatingLabelBehavior:FloatingLabelBehavior.never, 
        ),
      ),
)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. But in this line [floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,] I got error

Comment: You can remove it if you want !!!!